# how to use predefined formula from database and use it in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a page where user can select and define their own formula for calculating "WORKLOAD" of lecturers

For example,  (Jobtypevalue + Creditpoint) * Number of Students

I store this defined formula by the user in database.

Now, I want use this formula in another page which are fields (textbox) through which user can enter any number and at the bottom I need to calculate by using values entered by user based on the predefined formula from the database

If user enters Jobtypevalue = 7, Creditpoint = 3 and Number of students = 10
Then, at the bottom of page, I need calculate [(7+3)*10] and display "Workload = 100"

How can I do this using javascript ? Since, I have the formula on pageload from database and values are entered by user later, thought it is better to calculate the workload using javescript(client side)

Comment: Fixed number of operations? i.e first add var1,var2 and then multiply with var3. Or number and type of operations are variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this but your variable name should follow proper naming convention

```
//values in variables
var Jobtypevalue =7;
var Creditpoint = 3;
var Number_of_Students=10;

//use eval to evalute.
alert(eval("(Jobtypevalue + Creditpoint) * Number_of_Students"));
```

You can check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fCkUk/)**

Comment: Do not think this is all what needed in question still +1.. because whatever would be the right solution will need eval

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the formula "Jobtypevalue + Creditpoint) * Number_of_Students"

I can place the user defined formula stored in database, on a textbox and how do I use the formula from text box and calculate the values based on the formula.

Comment: @Raj you are getting it from db so you can store it in a hidden field or you can store it in a js variable like `var formula= '<%= your db formula field value %>';`

Comment: If I have,
textbox_formula.value = (Jobtypevalue + Creditpoint) * Number_of_Students


alert(eval(texbox.value)

Comment: @Raj, yes but need to create variables and assign values before calling this eval function.